# Android Http Post streaming json

Tags: android, json, http, post, streaming

I ran into trouble trying to send SQLite data to a web server using json (gson).
Everything was fine until the table came round 6000 rows.
I ran into Out of Memory errors.

In my datahelper I have:

```
public String DonneesToJson (SQLiteDatabase db, int chantier, int chantier_serveur )
{
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+P_TABLE+" where "+P_CHANTIER+"="+chantier+ " order by "+P_TIME+" desc ", null);

    List<Donnees> donnees = new ArrayList<Donnees>();
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        Donnees d = new Donnees (
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ID)),
                chantier_serveur,
                offset,
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PLAN)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_TIME)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PRESSION)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PROFONDEUR)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PROFONDEUR_TOTALE)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ANGLE_X)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ANGLE_Y)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PIEU)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_NO_RALLONGE)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_RALLONGE)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_MOTEUR)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_SERIE)),
                c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_COEFF_A)),
                c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_COEFF_B))
        );
        donnees.add(d);
    }

    c.close();

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    return gson.toJson(donnees);
}
```

Basically I call this like that:

```
String resultat = dbHelper.DonneesToJson(db,i, chantier_serveur);

HttpPost post2 = new HttpPost("http://www.zzzzzzz.com/test.php");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(resultat);  
se.setContentEncoding( new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post2.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(post2);
```

On the server side, it's quite basic php to store data in a big sql DB and then do analysis.

ie:
 `$decoded = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,true);
foreach ( $decoded as $key => $value)
{
$query = ...`

While doing OOM erros, it's slow. I mean getting sql data to json is slow.

I tried to go the jackson route, faster, no out of memory error, but... it can only write to a file or a stream.
I'd try to avoid writing to a file then send the file trough http post.
So I decided to open an http stream to send json data and I'm stuck.
I did not find any example on how to open an output stream to the web server using apache.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So, um, yeah... How about not sending **6000 rows** of data up/down the pipe? Perhaps split the data in batches?

Comment: One more vote for not sending 6000 rows of data.  dmon should post this as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: I tried to split in 1000 batches, but 7 minutes to transfer data is really too long. That why I was thinking about streaming data in order to limit data manipulations and memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the answer from dmon to split the data into batches, you should work on other glitches. Try this code:

```
public String DonneesToJson (SQLiteDatabase db, int chantier, int chantier_serveur ) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+P_TABLE+" where "+P_CHANTIER+"="+chantier+ " order by "+P_TIME+" desc ", null);

    List<Donnees> donnees = new ArrayList<Donnees>();
    if (c != null) { // nullcheck as rawQuery can return null!
        Donnees d; // reuse variables for loops
        while (c.moveToNext()) { // was buggy before, read comment below code
            d = new Donnees (
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ID)),
                chantier_serveur,
                offset,
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PLAN)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_TIME)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PRESSION)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PROFONDEUR)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PROFONDEUR_TOTALE)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ANGLE_X)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_ANGLE_Y)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_PIEU)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_NO_RALLONGE)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_RALLONGE)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_MOTEUR)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_SERIE)),
                c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_COEFF_A)),
                c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.P_COEFF_B)));
            donnees.add(d);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return new Gson().toJson(donnees);
}
```

Your current implementation is buggy and you will never get the first entry. The reason for that is your call to `moveToFirst()` which moves you to the first. The while loop will move the internal pointer to the second entry with `moveToNext()` which will result in starting with the second element and completely ignoring the first one. Always and forever...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this to me.
I know that there was a bug because I was missing some lines but did not saw the mistake.
I will try that and check memory.

Comment: Just to make it clear: This code doesn't do the batch post. I strongly recommend to do that. Another tip: If possible, find out if you can calculate some of the values you try to send. So if you send `a` and `b` and the addition `a+b`, then remove the addition and calculate that on the server side to reduce the bandwith. For example: send `chantier_serveur` and `offset` separately, as this seems to be the same for every entry...

Comment: Yes I removed the chantier_serveur and the offset, no need of them anymore, it was just for a test in fact.
All the other values are needed and I can't do any calculation on them before sending.